# how to reuse a vue component with different props

Tags: vue.js

I have created a component called dynamicTable which accepts a config as a prop

so on my sample.vue file which is the parent

```
<template>
 <div>
   <dynamicTable :config="config"></dynamicTable>

   <el-dialog title="modal" :visible.sync="modal">
      <dynamicTable :config="modal_config"></dynamicTable>
   </el-dialog>
 </div>
</template>
```

so the problem here is the dynamicTable that is not in the modal gets the configuration of the dynamicTable on the modal.

what i want is that each dynamic table has its own cofiguration without affecting the other

Comment: "the dynamicTable that is not in the modal gets the configuration of the dynamicTable on the modal." ?!!!!!

Comment: yes. somehow they share same config even if its on different variable

Comment: As you have mentioned config prop is not same for both cases . Try to differentiate type of config in dynamicTable, so adjust logic according to the type . You can add another prop or metion type of config in config prop

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably not a general component prop problem.

This should run OK for any `prop` inside any `custom-component`:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <custom-component prop="A"></custom-component>

   <el-dialog :visible.sync="modal">
      <custom-component prop="B"></custom-component>
   </el-dialog>
 </div>
</template>
```

So my guess is that your problem is on creating / updating `config` and `modal_config`.

My personal favorite way to check data values in real-time is by using Vue.js dev tools for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/vue-js-devtools/).